# Issue with '___ was unexpected at this time' in batch coding a text-based game

Tags: batch-file

I keep getting this issue when trying to do inputs and outcomes to inputs. I don't know what the issue is and I'd like to know so that I wouldn't have to solve this puzzle every time I came across it by reprogramming it. Here's what the code looks like:

```
:A1
cls
type A1intro.txt

echo.
echo.
set input=5
set /p input=NOW WHAT? 
if %input%==HELP goto A1HELP
if %input%==LOOK goto A1LOOK
if %input%==LOOK AT BED goto A1BED ***this is where it says 'A1 not expected' once I type LOOK AT BED in the input***

goto A1


:A1BED ***So, this is where the A1 bed goes to and where the issue is with the code. No other command does this except this one. The others are identical in their coding.***

cls
type A1bed.txt
echo.
echo.
pause
goto A1
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you need quotes around the comparison?

```
if "%input%"=="LOOK AT BED" goto A1BED
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need quotes around Line 11 otherwise cmd.exe thinks your comparison string is just `LOOK`